# WebLogic 12C app server version -12.2.1.2.0 Class Loader issue

Tags: hibernate, java-8, classloader, weblogic12c

when I load the .ear file to WL12C app server it is failing due to the following error: 
"    <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <0be88d61-a836-4510-8937-873683a9bc03-0000004e> <1548447814363> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] >

The same .ear file gets deployed to my local WL12C on my work station without any issues. but the issue comes when it is being deployed to DEV environment app server.

Comment: "<Error> <Deployer> <DEVWLSAPP01> <devwlsapp01_7001> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0be88d61-a836-4510-8937-873683a9bc03-0000004e> <1548447814363> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "ALL_ENV_WL12_DEV_2019-01-25_003_v5_32_0_11".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"

Comment: it's clear Hibernate classes are missing. Did you check them already ?